# Seperate values based on property value and show with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var array = [[
    { "loc": {} },
    { "distance": 6.4 },
    { "zip1": "06120" },
    { "zip2": "06095" },
    { "group": 1 },
    { "weight": 1119 }
], [
    { "loc": {} },
    { "distance": 6.41 },
    { "zip1": "06095" },
    { "zip2": "06120" },
    { "group": 2 },
    { "weight": 41976 }
], [
    { "loc": {} },
    { "distance": 6.41 },
    { "zip1": "06095" },
    { "zip2": "06120" },
    { "group": 1 },
    { "weight": 41976 }
]];
```

Now I want to take the array values based on the property values for show in HTML.
Expected output is split into array with "group" property. I also need to store in HTML with based on group, as shown in the example below:

```
group 1:
  all zip1's under group 1
group 2:
  all zip1's under group 2
```

I tried using a loop but I didn't manage to get the right answer:

```
for (var k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
    var array1 = array[k];    
    if (flag[array1[2]["zip1"]]) continue;
    flag[array1[2]["zip1"]] = true;
    output2.push(array1);
}
```

So help me to find split the array show in HTML with group wise

[image: sample output]

Comment: Can you include the actual expected output at the question? What do you mean by "under" at _"all zip1's under group 1"_ and _"all zip1's under group 2"_?

Comment: yes i will update it

Comment: @Saravanan Fixed the format for you

Comment: Are `"zip2"` property values omitted from the procedure?

Comment: @guest271314 no i need everything.Just i say zip1 for example

Comment: Can you print the actual expected output at the question. The image and _"group 1:
  all zip1's under group 1
group 2:
  all zip1's under group 2"_ is not entirely clear as to what the requirement is.

Comment: yes wait please @guest271314

Comment: @guest271314, Please see my updated image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reduce`, you can create an object with each `group` value as key and an array of `zip1` as values like this:

Then loop through the `Object.entries`, to create the HTML:

```js
const array = [[{"loc":{}},{"distance":6.4},{"zip1":"06120"},{"zip2":"06095"},{"group":1},{"weight":1119}],[{"loc":{}},{"distance":6.41},{"zip1":"06095"},{"zip2":"06120"},{"group":2},{"weight":41976}],[{"loc":{}},{"distance":6.41},{"zip1":"06095"},{"zip2":"06120"},{"group":1},{"weight":41976}]];

const merged = array.reduce((r, a) =>{
  const { group } = a.find(n => n.group)
  const { zip1 } = a.find(n => n.zip1)
  r[group] = r[group] || []
  r[group].push(zip1)
  return r;
},{})

const output = document.getElementById('output');

Object.entries(merged).forEach(([group, zips]) => {
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.innerHTML = "group " + group
  
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = `Zip1 - ${zips} (in group - ${group})`;
  
  output.appendChild(h1)
  output.appendChild(span)
})
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: thanks.can i store all values with properties like "zip1":12548,"zip2":25368

Comment: @Saravanan If the answer helped you, you can up-vote it and accept it

Comment: answer is helped but i need store with properties.like i above commented.and i want all values.Help me for this

Comment: @Saravanan added the HTML part as well

Comment: how can i get zip2 and others also @adiga