# How to push all values into array and get them with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I have my previous question in this link [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802407/seperate-values-based-on-property-value-and-show-with-javascript)

I asked to push all values into an array and show to the HTML. They responded well but it showing only one value(zip1) into an array and get them to HTML.

So i want to get that all values like zip1,zip2, distance, weight based on the group number.

I tried but answer not came
my code altered from previous answer.

```
const array = [[{"loc":{}},{"distance":6.4},{"zip1":"06120"},{"zip2":"06095"},{"group":1},{"weight":1119}],[{"loc":{}},{"distance":6.41},{"zip1":"06095"},{"zip2":"06120"},{"group":2},{"weight":41976}],[{"loc":{}},{"distance":6.41},{"zip1":"06095"},{"zip2":"06120"},{"group":1},{"weight":41976}]];

const merged = array.map((r, a) =>{
  const { group } = a.find(n => n.group)
  const { zip1 } = a.find(n => n.zip1)
  r[group] = r[group] || []
  r[group].push({Zip1:zip1})
   const { zip2 } = a.find(n => n.zip2)
    r[group].push({Zip2:zip2})
     const { weight } = a.find(n => n.weight)
    r[group].push({weight:weight})
     const { distance } = a.find(n => n.distance)
    r[group].push({distance:distance})
  return r;
},{})
const output = document.getElementById('output');

Object.entries(merged).forEach(([group, zips]) => {
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.innerHTML = "group " + group

  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = `Zip1 - ${zips.zip1},${zips.zip2},${zips.weight},${zips.distance} (in group - ${group})`;

  output.appendChild(h1)
  output.appendChild(span)
})
```

My expected output(but I need to show this in google map infowindow.I just showing example content)
[image: sample output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Methodology

1. **Convert your 2D array into a 1D array**, so instead of having *arrays* as inner items you will have *objects*. This is done through the `arrToObj` function
2. **Convert your `zip` values from *string* to *array***. This is done to facilitate their _concatenation in the future. Done through the `zipToArr` function
3. **Group your *array* of objects under one *object***. In order to do that we *promote* the `group` key and *concatenate* `zip1/zip2` with other objects from the same group. Refer to the `grouper` function
4. **Get the grouped objects** using `Object.values` on the previous *aggregate*. We already have the `group` key in them so we don't need the *parent* key anymore
5. **Format your values into HTML elements** based on their respective *keys*. This will facilitate generating the HTML in the end since we'll have the elements ready. Done with `html` and `format` functions
6. **Render your HTML** by iterating on the previously generated array. In each iteration create a *container `div`* that will hold the *group*. The container will help styling its *first element* `group`

## Implementation

```js
const array = [[{"loc":{}},{"distance":6.4},{"zip1":"06120"},{"zip2":"06095"},{"group":1},{"weight":1119}],[{"loc":{}},{"distance":6.41},{"zip1":"06095"},{"zip2":"06120"},{"group":2},{"weight":41976}],[{"loc":{}},{"distance":6.41},{"zip1":"06095"},{"zip2":"06120"},{"group":1},{"weight":41976}]];

// Data processing functions
const arrToObj = arr => arr.reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, ...c}), {});
const zipToArr = x => ({...x, zip1: [x.zip1], zip2: [x.zip2]});
const grouper = (a, c) => {
  delete c.loc;
  delete c.distance;
  if (a[c.group]) {
    a[c.group].zip1.push(...c.zip1);
    a[c.group].zip2.push(...c.zip2);
    return a;
  } else {
    return {...a, [c.group]: c}
  }
};

// HTML utilities
const html = (k, v) => {
  const it = document.createElement('p');
  it.innerHTML = `${k} ${v}`;
  return it; 
}
const format = g => Object.keys(g).sort().reduce((a, c) => ({...a, [c]: html(c, g[c])}), {});

// Actual processing
const data = array.map(arrToObj).map(zipToArr).reduce(grouper, {});
const dataWithHTML = Object.values(data).map(format);

// Rendering
const display = document.getElementById('display');
dataWithHTML.forEach(it => {
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  Object.values(it).forEach(v => container.appendChild(v));
  display.appendChild(container);
});
```

```css
p:first-of-type {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
 }

p {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```